# Temporary home directory CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

I would like to setup a linux machine that students can use to login and work on virtual machines. I would like the following behavior to happen from start to finish. This is a classroom environment and I do not want any changes that a student makes to persist upon logoff/reboot.

1. User logs in with username/password.
2. The user performs his or her work on the machine.
3. The user logs off or shuts down the machine.
4. The home directory is restored to a known or default state.
5. Repeat for another user.

Is there a way to do this or is there a better way to think through this that I am missing?

Comment: If the user has an account, then they already have a home directory! [What is the _real_ problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) that you think this will solve?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, that's not always true and the reason we have `pam_mkhomedir`

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is a classroom environment and I do not want a student's changes to the home directory to persist after a logoff/reboot

Comment: Why not just roll back the VM to a snapshot, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's a physical machine running Virtualbox

Comment: Have you considered using Docker for this?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew -

What you are looking to do is built right into linux! You want to use the .bash_logout mechanism to wipe all contents on the user's home directory on logout, and upon logging in, those files should be restored. If not, add a line to copy them back in.

You could do this with something like this:

**.bash_logout**

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf *
```

You can put that file into /etc/skel and all new users will have the file when they are created. Also create any other folders that you want to have in their home directory that don't exist in /etc/skel, like Documents, Downloads, etc.

If the files aren't automatically put back into the home folder, just add this to the end of .bash_logout

`cp -r /etc/skel ./`